# How to store output of Java code when using NodeJS child_processor

Tags: node.js, child-process

Hello can I please get some assistance here, so I am using the NodeJS `child_process` module to access my `Javac` so I want to know how can I have the output stored in memory so I can run some checks on whether that was the desired output or not

**Code below is how I compile and run code**

```
const spawn = CHildePorceossor.spawn;
const opts: SpawnOptions = { stdio: 'inherit' };
const javac = spawn('javac', ['./Test.java'], opts);
javac.on('close', function (code) {
  if (code === 0) {
    const java = spawn('java', ['Test'], opts);
  }
});
```

- When I log out **java** I get the following which is not having my output

```
ref *1> ChildProcess {
  _events: [Object: null prototype] {},
  _eventsCount: 0,
  _maxListeners: undefined,
  _closesNeeded: 1,
  _closesGot: 0,
  connected: false,
  signalCode: null,
  exitCode: null,
  killed: false,
  spawnfile: 'java',
  _handle: Process {
    onexit: [Function (anonymous)],
    pid: 24155,
    [Symbol(owner_symbol)]: [Circular *1]
  },
  spawnargs: [ 'java', 'Test' ],
  pid: 24155,
  stdin: null,
  stdout: null,
  stderr: null,
  stdio: [ null, null, null ],
  [Symbol(kCapture)]: false
}
```

- The expected output is just automatically logged out to console and never stored in that java variable
- Is the a way I can store that expected out?

Comment: execFile or exec is probably more what you're looking for, if you want to use spawn you'll likely need to hook onto the stdout socket. Use util.promisify on either of those and you'll get a simple `let output = await exec('myprocess')` --- be aware of the buffer limit that can be increased with the options

Comment: @CodyＧ I hear what you are saying but I seem to be a bit lost do you mind giving me an example on how I can implement what you are saying or maybe refer me to a read where I can read about what you are saying please

Comment: https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_exec_command_options_callback